# Braintree API not working in PHP Application

Tags: php, payment-gateway, braintree

I have an app that contains many folders/subfolders/files and I can't seem to get Braintree to function correctly.  Is there something I'm simply missing here? Let's say my site name is DIR.

All the files unzipped from the braintree folder are in DIR/braintree_payments

Then my transaction.php file is in DIR/templates/content/listing

All the labels for the form are in DIR/templates/content/listing/confirm_booking.tpl.php

```
confirm_booking.tpl.php
                <h1>Braintree Credit Card Transaction Form</h1>
                    <div style="position:relative;">
                      <form action="transaction.php" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
                        <p>
                          <label>Card Number</label>
                          <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>CVV</label>
                          <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
                          <input type="text" size="2" name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" name="year" />
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      var braintree = Braintree.create("awefawef2oIaXiawefawefawefoP1jJ3LNuLchxfeawfawetq34tq34tq34tBtfTk6KnM0Bk3TkofNMM2CG/1ktaBDa+BEbteZjF05e5Jjfwefawfawe4t34434CVxaXNAbgZEn+ECWiZ2rynxtme5goMAhYAS+blBaVlL9+affawef aw/NLhqKmwQL7zuK3GBGiOp3ht9rL3AI1O84o1WpjVeqt8Xgg5MQe4jRTGJAfR3Rv25KPuwRaTqrevyVyRkPekcCIp1HROoZGelQyaSsPzhA0/FApbRu0Vpcx6kUwIDAQAB");
                      braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
                    </script>



transaction.php

<?PHP
require_once 'braintree_payments/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('389yhf9gf82gf3');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('r3h89h39h833');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('my_private_api_key');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    "amount" => "1000.00",
    "creditCard" => array(
        "number" => $_POST["number"],
        "cvv" => $_POST["cvv"],
        "expirationMonth" => $_POST["month"],
        "expirationYear" => $_POST["year"]
    ),
    "options" => array(
        "submitForSettlement" => true
    )
));

if ($result->success) {
    echo("Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
    echo("Error: " . $result->message);
    echo("<br/>");
    echo("Code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
} else {
    echo("Validation errors:<br/>");
    foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
        echo("- " . $error->message . "<br/>");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Also the page that contains the html of confirm_booking.tpl.php is linked from DIR/modules/listing/confirm_booking.php.  So modules/listing/confirm_booking.php is in the url

Comment: Hey @pmanning, did you try adding `../` in your `require_once`? `require_once '../braintree_payments/lib/Braintree.php';` If that doesn't fix it, please be more specific then "doesn't function correctly" Also, I've edited your post to remove your private key. Even though it's only a sandbox account, you should keep that private.

Comment: yeah i tried that no luck.  and thanks for the edit but i just scribbled in some text those aren't the real keys.  It redirects to my home page, and then nothing shows up in my sandbox account.

Comment: What shows up in your console / logs? Does it say "Success" or "Error" or anything else?

Comment: I am working on this - if you look in the braintree/lib/Braintree.php at the bottom you'll see where it is supposed to throw errors saying "Briantree requires extension X". I changed that to an echo statement and found 2 extensions that I need to install. Not sure if that will get things working but that is where I am at right now.

Comment: thanks chris, im working with another developer currently to implement it. i'll let you know what we find.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you are experiencing, but maybe this will help someone.

I was running in the Braintree Sandbox with a form.php and transaction.php file. In the transaction.php, I did `require_once('/lib/Braintree.php');` and the transaction.php was just dying, never getting past the `require_once` statement.

I went into Braintree.php, to the bottom of the file, and found the line that says `throw new Braintree_Exception('The Braintree library requires the ' . $ext . ' extension.');`

For whatever reason, this is the line where my script was dying. I changed the `throw new` to an `echo` and ran my transaction.php file again - and got 2 messages saying "The Braintree library requires the XXXX extension".

For me, it was the xml-writer extension. I went on my server, installed xml-writer, and restarted Apache. Then everything worked as expected.

Comment: I did this too, but it still fails. I guess something is wrong with autoload.php